# Android Studio: SharedPreferences not working between activities

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences

I'm currently working on an android app where I want to add a login/logout system using JDBC for the SQL and SharedPreferences to handle the sessions, the SQL works perfectly but when i go from the login activity to the main activity and try to get the values in the sharedpreferences it returns the default values.

Here is my Login Activity:

```
private TextView usernameHeader, passwordHeader;
private EditText username, password;
private Button loginButton;
private Handler alertHandler;
private String userRes, passwdRes;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static final String MySession = "MySession";
public static final String nameField = "nameKey";
public static final String passwordField = "passwordKey";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwd);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sqlThread.start(); //The loginIntent is called inside the thread using a handler
        }
    });

}

public void loginIntent(){

    try{
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MySession, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString(nameField, userRes);
        editor.putString(passwordField, passwdRes);
        editor.apply();
        //editor.commit();

    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Here's my Main Activity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(mapView);
    map = new ArcGISMap(Basemap.Type.TOPOGRAPHIC, 34.056295, -117.195800, 16);
    mMapView.setMap(map);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.MySession, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    name = (String) sharedPreferences.getString(LoginActivity.nameField,"");

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The Toast output is empty.

Comment: editor.commit(); may help

Comment: name = (String) sharedPreferences.getString(LoginActivity.nameField,""); You don't need to cast it into String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried checking out the values of the variables `userRes` and `passwdRes`? Based on the codes you have provided on your post, they may not have been initialized.

Comment: It was the variables, they were initialized in the sqlthread but their values were null, i fixed the variables issue and now it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try `editor.commit()`.

`editor.apply()` is asynchronous. and your LoginActivity jumps directly to the Main Activity and requests the stored info. It *might be* that the MainActivity is requesting the strings before they are committed to the storage.